# How do I know my mac turns off because of overheating?

Tags: logs, shutdown, temperature, cooling

My Macbook Pro (Yosemite)  early 2011 sometimes unexpectedly turns off when running heavy tasks on battery power. Is there a way to confirm this is because of overheating?

Here's a part of system.log from the moment of shutdown. What other logs can I read?

> Feb 24 08:22:56 macs-MacBook-Pro.local Skype[281]: Failed to get
> contents of directory "/Users/mac/Library/Logs/Skype". The file
> “Skype” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. Feb 24
>
> 08:24:47 macs-MacBook-Pro systemstatsd[583]: assertion failed: 14C109:
> systemstatsd + 4269 [A886B71F-3A31-3324-9B30-5143FDF4ECCB]: 0xb Feb 24
>
> 08:24:47 macs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
> (com.apple.systemstatsd[583]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
>
> Feb 24 08:54:10 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1424764450 0

Comment: are the cooling fans running at full blast for more than 5 minutes

Comment: It's more likely to be a problem with the battery. Old batteries shutting off under high load is a common occurrence, as with iPhones.

Comment: IME, one likely cause is dust build-up inside the machine, rendering the fans less and less effective.  Unfortunately, it's not easy to open up MacBooks to clean out the airways.

Comment: What makes you believe it’s overheating when nothing in your logs you provided indicate that. I agree with @benwiggy that your battery is the most logical culprit. Please follow the [instructions in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271) to get the shutdown cause so we can start trying to track down the issue you’re experiencing

Comment: @146438 Why the bounty? This is a 9-year-old, specific issue with limited information, and a fairly speculative answer. (It's a list of good things to try, granted.)

Answer (score 1):

It would not do that until:

First the fans go at full speed for few minutes. You would hear that.

If that does not keep the temperature from climbing, it would cut down the CPU power. You would feel that in computer becoming sluggish (slow).

Normally the above is sufficient to prevent overheating.

If all that has failed it would not just shut down, it will try to shut down correctly.

Look in the Console for kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: ?

You could look in to Activity Monitor to see what is happening while under stress.

There is also a app called [Istat](http://istat-pro.soft32.com/) that displays lots of parameters.