# How to detect if Mac if rebooting after a power failure using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, power-management

As I asked in the title, how can I check if a Mac is rebooting after experiencing a power failure. It would be preferable to check this using terminal or some other script, as I would like to test this automatically in a script upon system startup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for the "Shutdown Cause" in the log.

- 5 is a normal shutdown
- 3 is pressing the power button
- 0 is loss of power

In El Capitan and earlier:

```
cat /var/log/system.log | grep -i "shutdown cause"
```

In Sierra and newer:

```
log show --predicate "process == kernel" | grep -i "shutdown cause"
```

Or....just using `awk` to get the code:

```
log show --predicate "process == kernel" | awk '/shutdown cause/ {print $12}'
```

In Mojave and Catalina, you can issue the command to get a more fine grained approach to the log:

```
log show --predicate '(process = "kernel") && (eventMessage CONTAINS "shutdown cause")' --last 48h --style compact
```

This will process only the last 48 hours and output in a nice "compact" layout.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra, when I run the command it returns "log: invalid predicate:
[<OSLogEventProxy 0x7fbd9a50b1e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key kernel."

Comment: Then do a more obvious test : remove the power, restore the power and see if it reboots. Results will be obvious....

Comment: Try it without the `--predicate = "process == kernel"

Comment: I get "2017-11-07 17:57:15.707333-0800 0xa5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5" 
Is there a command/script I can use to just get the number out of the string?

Comment: Try `log show | awk '/shutdown cause/ {print $12}'`  That should just give you the number.

Comment: @allan Ive tried `cat /var/log/system.log | grep -i "shutdown cause"` on a machine running 10.11.6 and it just gives me blank new prompt line, same if i run it sudo. Any ideas ?

Comment: @sam - is there anything in the log itself?

Comment: @Allan its strange, i just re ran the 10.11 terminal command and it gave me a `5` response in the log for about half an hour ago, but nothing for any previous days, im trying to diagnose somthing that happened on 9/Nov, but its not showing up

Comment: Not strange.  After a certain amount of time, your log get's "archived" as it will only hold so much.  They will be named `/var/log/system.log.XX.gz`.  You will have to unzip them first to be able to view them.

Answer (score 2):

In High Sierra, 10.13.5 I used System Information (alt About this Mac) to examine the Power Management log, under Software/Logs.

This clearly showed I'd had a power cut at or shortly after 02:35:14 am. I originally spotted it when the clock on my microwave showed 00:00. Below you cans see the power off and reboot times.

---

2018-07-07 02:35:14 +0100 Assertions              PID 39(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.backupd-auto" 00:00:34  id:0x0xb00009108 [System: BGTask]

Time stamp                Domain                  Message                                                                        Duration      Delay
==========                ======                  =======                                                                        ========      =====
UUID: (null)
2018-07-07 10:25:13 +0100 Start                   powerd process is started