# MacBook shutting down when I put it to sleep with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, closed-clamshell

I have a MacBook Pro 13" (2020 running mac os Catalina)and it's connected to an LG 4k display (in clamshell mode). When I stop using it, I put it to sleep by either using the launch bar or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⏏</kbd>. It sleeps but when I leave it for a while, it shut down and I have to restart it by pressing the power button.

I leave the MacBook both charging and connected to the display, however when I want to use it again, I've noticed that it had shut down and I have to restart it by opening the lid and pressing the power button, how do I fix that?

Comment: First, you need to get the "shutdown cause" to see what's triggering the shutdown.  You didn't mention the version of macOS, so see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271) for Terminal commands covering various versions of macOS.  [Edit] your answer with the results from the command and ther version of macOS you're using.

Comment: Also, just for clarification, pressing keys on your external keyboard don't wake it up?

Comment: pressing keys on my external magic keyboard doesn't do anything, im running mac os Catalina

Comment: I'm also facing the issues on MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017).
This is happening only after updating the mac OS from high sierra to mac OS Catalina 10.15.5