# When using a dummy VGA projector, some of the software does not appear on my built-in retina screen

Tags: display

[image]So the reason I attached a VGA dummy to my mid-2014 retina Macbook is to solve [this problem](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/320496/Randomly+shuts+down+when+not+connected+to+an+external+display.) which it did. But now I have a new problem. From time to time, if I try to open a software, it won't appear on my retina screen. It reappears if I unplug the VGA Dummy. However, the problem does not appear consistently. Sometimes if I restart my Mac it disappears, at least for a while. And I am not a hundred percent sure, but it never happens with Chrome, only calendar, texshop or office softwares.

Please help me because this is seriously hampering my ability to work

Comment: window most likely shows up there.

Comment: How about getting the issue with the random shutdowns fixed?  This is like towing  a trailer because when you don’t the rear end gets squirreley and causes you to crash.  The fix isn’t to tow a trailer for the rest of the vehicle’s life, it’s to fix the underlying problem!

Comment: @Allan,thanks but I don't know how to fix it. I tried various method including reinstall my OSX，but nothing works except this method. If you have any suggestion, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are posts here on how to get the “shutdown cause” of the Mac. Run one of the commands found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271 once you have the info, *search* to see if it’s already been asked.  If not Ask a new one and post the details (it’s different from this question altogether).  It's possible the problem/fix is cost prohibitive, but then again, so cheap and easy you’ll  wonder why you put up with it for so long.  I’ll  help however I can.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the VGA dummy as a secondary monitor, and most likely you have it configured as your primary monitor. Try this: Open Preferences -> Monitors -> Arrange and drag-n-drop the menu bar to your built-in retina display. Alternatively, you can choose to mirror your screen onto the (non-existent) external monitor, which should absolutely fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, I have attached the display screen capture(I didn't find the monitors option). Would you please kindly confirm this is the right one?