# Mac Mini (Late 2012) is giving 'unexpectedly shut down' message each morning

Tags: mac-mini, kernel-panic

This problem only recently started, after I changed the location of my computer in the house.  It's happened twice this week already, when I've left my computer on overnight.  When I log on, I'm getting a message in the morning that says the computer unexpectedly shut down.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Wed Aug 26 05:41:41 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800debc42f):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

uuid info:
 0x1134c5000    uuid = <dfc3c4af-6f97-3b34-b18d-7dcb23f2a83a>
 0x104a32000    uuid = <bbd445b6-fba9-3a9c-828f-a112f63e2080>

Thread 2 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000104a80068, RCX: 0x0000000104a7d000, RDX: 0x0000000104a80088
RSP: 0x0000700003d7d390, RBP: 0x0000700003d7d430, RSI: 0x0000000104a80078, RDI: 0x0000000104a32000
R8:  0x0000000104a32ae8, R9:  0x0000000000000d0e, R10: 0x0000000000000010, R11: 0x0000000000000202
R12: 0x0000000100021a7a, R13: 0x0000000000001eb0, R14: 0x0000000104a82748, R15: 0x0000000104a32000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0x00007fff71eecb7f, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff802d71c000
    0x00007fff72027126
    0x00007fff71eb0ede
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff8039fbaa40
    0x00007fff7204229e
    0x00007fff71ea3de6
    0x00007fff71eb2f42
    0x00007fff71ea7792
    0x00007fff71ea8396
    0x00007fff71eb06ed
    0x00007fff720e1611
    0x00007fff720e13fd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff803a00b520
    0x00007fff71eecb7f
    0x00007fff71eeca07
    0x00007fff71eec8d1
    0x00007fff71f49b2a
    0x0000000104a53a7a
    0x0000000104a64439
    0x00007fff71ea163d
    0x00007fff71ea3de6
    0x00007fff71eb2f42
    0x00007fff71ea7792
    0x00007fff71ea8396
    0x00007fff71eb06ed
    0x00007fff720e1611
    0x00007fff720e13fd
    0x8000120065727473

Thread 3: 0xffffff803621ba40
    0x00007fff720e13f0

Thread 4: 0xffffff802df81000
    0x00007fff720e13f0


Mac OS version:
18G103

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
System model name: Macmini6,1 (Mac-031AEE4D24BFF0B1)

EOF
Model: Macmini6,1, BootROM 280.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.7f1
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD4000Item, Intel HD Graphics 4000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331312D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331312D38475351000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.33 AirPortDriverBrcm4360-1325.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.1 Device
USB Device: USB Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

....And as requested (thanks for the suggestions so far, btw), here is what is produced when I run the shutdown cause command.

```
Mac-Mini:~ critical1$ log show --predicate '(process = "kernel") && (eventMessage CONTAINS "shutdown cause")' --last 48h --style compact
Filtering the log data using "process == "kernel" AND composedMessage CONTAINS "shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp               Ty Process[PID:TID]
2020-08-26 05:41:30.896 Df kernel[0:a4] (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
```

Comment: Can you put it back to the previous location for a few days and see whether the problem occurs there as well?

Comment: Let's also check the logs for the Shutdown Cause.  See [Obtain the Shutdown Cause](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271) for your particular version of macOS.  [Edit] your question with the results.

Comment: FYI... You don't have to include the whole command - simply say that the shutdown cause was "5" is sufficient.  That indicates a normal shutdown so something is telling your computer to turn off and it is.  It seems that during the shutdown something isn't gracefully closing so it crashes.  In other words, this crash isn't causing the shutdown, but the shutdown is causing this app to crash.  What are your energy settings?  Do you have this mini plugged into a UPS?