# Does Shutdown -r command write to system log?

Tags: terminal, shutdown, logs

`man shutdown` reads the following:

```
At shutdown time a message is written to the system log, containing the
     time of shutdown, the person who initiated the shutdown and the reason.
     Corresponding signal is then sent to launchd(8) to respectively halt,
     reboot or bring the system down to single-user state (depending on the
     above options).
```

I've tried it on Catalina but when I go to `/var/log/system.log` I don't see any indication of my shutdown.

I tested both `-r` and `-h` options but still nothing.

How can I get my planned shutdowns logged in the system log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After High Sierra, it uses a different logging system.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271) for command related to getting the shutdown entry

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/console/locate-a-log-file-cnsl9361/mac

Comment: hello @Allan! Do you know of a way to make Catalina behave more like a Linux machine and log things to a log file instead of using log command? Or can I output this log to a file?

Comment: That’s not feasible as far as I know. Apple’s tools are designed to utilized the new. Logging system.  Syslog is there for legacy compatibility